# Sequelize - return rows from one table based on counts in another table

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am having trouble figuring out this query in Sequelize. Suppose I have a table of "contestants." I also have a table of "contestant_ratings." Every contestant can have many ratings in that ratings table. Contestant.hasMany(ContestantRatings) ... And I want to query contestants and only return them if they have less than 10 ratings in the contestant_ratings table. I'm using sequelize with postgres.

Sample data:

```
// Contestant ratings table
id.   name.   rating.   contestant_id    
1.    Rob.    9.        78
2.    Colin.  7.        101
3.    Fatima. 10.       50
4.    Rob.    9.        78
5.    Rob.    7.        78
6.    Rob.    9.        78
7.    Rob.    4.        78
8.    Rob.    9.        78
9.    Rob.    3.        78
10.    Rob.    9.        78
11.    Rob.    6.        78
12.    Rob.    4.        78
13.    Rob.    7.        78

// Contestant table
id.    name. 
78.    Rob.
101.   Colin.
50.    Fatima.

// Expected output:
{ name: Colin, id: 101 }, { name: Fatima, id: 50 }
```

Comment: please clearify your que and put some code what you have did so far ?

Comment: use sequelize.literal in a where condition to achieve such condition.

Comment: I was able to do it (see below) without having to revert to a literal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution!

```
let characters = await Contestant.findAll({
                include: [{ model: ContestantRating }],
                attributes: [
                    [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('contestant_ratings.contestant_id')), 'contestant_id'],
                    'name'
                ],
                group: ['contestant_ratings.id', 'contestant.id'],
                having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('contestant_ratings.contestant_id')), {
                    [Op.lte]: 10
                  })

            })
```